# Adding elements to a panel in c#!

Tags: c#, wpf, hide, panel, element

quick question, in a c# Windows Presentation Foundation How can i add some elements to a Panel so i can easily hide all the elements (Text, Labels...) by just hiding the panel it self?
I have already tried to just put panels over the elements to hide them but i don't think that would be a neat solution because i would also hide all the other elements under it.
I need this because i am trying to have different forms in the same place and on the base of what the user types the items should appear. I don't want it to open a new window.

Thanks!

Comment: Please tag your question properly. If you're working with WPF, tag your question `[wpf]`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all your elements are in the same container, just set the Visibility property of the container to "Collapsed". Ideally, this would be by binding to a bool and using the BoolToVisibility converter provided in WPF.

If they are NOT in the same container, you are a bit out of luck. You will need to set/bind each of the element's visibility properties separately, but using the same techniques as above.

Answer (score 0):

If you place all of the elements you want on that panel you can tell that panel to be invisible or visible and all of the elements on that panel will hide or show accordingly.  For ease of use when you are programming you can right click on the panel and choose send back or bring forward and this will help you navigate your form while programming.

Comment: While technically correct, there is no "invisible" property in WPF. Using the correct keywords and potentially providing a code example make answers a lot more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Panel is a base class and has a Visibility property

[Panel Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
<StackPanel x:Name="pnl1" Grid.Row=0 Visibility="Collapsed">
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbTime" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbDate" />
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel x:Name="pnl2" Grid.Row=2 Visibility="Visible">
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbTime2" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="tbDate2" />
</StackPanel>
```